# Time command say `NAN`:`NaN` for song Duration

Tags: discord.js

This is the code of Time, `StreamTime` is the amount of time bot streamed the song, and `song.duration` is the Music duration time. My bot say `NaN`: `NaN` for `song.duration`

```
module.exports = {
  name: "time",
  description: "Show music time",
  execute(message, song, duration) {

    const queue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);       
    const dispatcher = queue.connection.dispatcher

    message.channel.send({
      embed: {
        color: 39935,  //random color between one and 16777214 (dec)
        author: {},
        title: "Time ⏳",
        color: 39935,
        description: `${Math.floor(dispatcher.streamTime / 60000)}:${Math.floor((dispatcher.streamTime % 60000)/1000) <10 ? '0'+Math.floor((dispatcher.streamTime % 60000)/1000) : Math.floor((dispatcher.streamTime % 60000)/1000)}  Duration: ${Math.floor(song.duration/60)}:${song.duration%60}`,          
        timestamp: new Date(),
        footer: {
          icon_url: message.client.user.avatarURL(),
          text: "© test"
        }
      }
    }); 
  }}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you please console.log song.duration and edit your question with the response?

Comment: I not have any error, console say nothing. i added ` }).catch(console.error);` and nothing told me an error